How to format specific ROWs in Dash DataTable when using a transposed DataFrame?
I have a DataFrame and I would like to apply some format styles to it... But the problem is that as I need to transpose the table and the value IDs are the columns and the "original" columns are now presented in the rows, as you can see in the image below:

I would like to find a way to format the values as following:
Hours Col should be 1,253 instead of 1253
Value Col should be $ 31,950,000 instead of 31950000
Below is a Minimal Reproducible Example to help you to reproduce and understand the problem I'm facing;
from dash import html, Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd

list_of_vals=[
    {'Val ID': '9729', 'Year Col': '2017', 'Hours Col': 1253.0, 'Value Col': 31950000.0}, 
    {'Val ID': '9733', 'Year Col': '2016', 'Hours Col': 2541.0, 'Value Col': 29995000.0},
    {'Val ID': '9837', 'Year Col': '2019', 'Hours Col': 566.0, 'Value Col': 34900000.0},
    {'Val ID': '9507', 'Year Col': '2013', 'Hours Col': 2732.0, 'Value Col': 26000000.0},
    {'Val ID': '9805', 'Year Col': '2018', 'Hours Col': 1543.0, 'Value Col': 31500000.0}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_vals)
df = df.set_index("Val ID").T
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "Val ID"})
data_list = [item for item in df.to_dict(orient="records")]

columns_list = list(df.columns)
app = Dash(
    __name__,
    title="Data table test",
)
cond_to_index = ["Val ID"]

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Data Table Test"),
        dash_table.DataTable(
        data_list,
        [
            {
                "name": i,
                "id": i,
                "editable": True if i != "Val ID" else False,
            }
            for (n, i) in enumerate(columns_list)
        ],
        # fixed_columns={"headers": True, "data": 1},
        style_header={"fontWeight": "bold"},
        style_table={"width": "100%"},
        style_header_conditional=[
            {
                "if": {"column_id": col},
                "textAlign": "left" if col == "Val ID" else "center",
                "fontSize": "14px",
            }
            for col in columns_list
        ],
        style_data_conditional=[
            {
                "if": {"column_id": col},
                "fontWeight": "bold" if col in cond_to_index else "normal",
                "width": "250px" if col in cond_to_index else "150px",
                "minWidth": "250px" if col in cond_to_index else "150px",
                "maxWidth": "250px" if col in cond_to_index else "150px",
                "textAlign": "left" if col in cond_to_index else "center",
                "fontSize": "12px",
                "paddingLeft": "4px" if col in cond_to_index else "0px",
            }
            for col in columns_list
        ],
        id="test-table",
    )], style={"maxWidth":"500px"}
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)

Does someone have any experience regarding this issue?
